# Sort order in template

Tags: sxa

How can we implement sort order functionality in template in Sitecore SXA?
For example :
We have three item in Sitecore Content editor :

```
**Name**    **Sort Order**
Test 1          1
Test 2          2
Test 3          0
```

If we select sort order in this way then the content editor structure will  be like this:

```
Test 3
Test 1
Test 2
```

We have same functionality in Appearance tab , need the same implementation when we would add it in template field..

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem.. what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: using sort order arrange the items in Content editor.

Comment: And what's wrong with the default options as described here: https://horizontal.blog/2016/03/11/sorting-items-in-sitecore/ ?

Answer (score -5):

I have modified my first answer following the comments of Michael West and Mark Cassidy in relation to the end of use of the Sitecore fast query but also because I think you don't need code for that. So I agree with Gatogordo. I think you can handle the order of child elements in the sub-element sorting section.

[image]
Gatogordo

[image]

Comment: I would highly encourage you to move away from the this approach as "fast" as possible. Fast Queries are no longer a feature recommended by Sitecore. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16203/what-are-the-limitations-of-fast-query https://intothecloud.blog/2018/10/21/It-s-time-to-put-fast-query-to-rest/

Comment: It's not about "being recommended". Fast queries are flat out no longer possible, from Sitecore 10 onwards.

Comment: Thank you guys for your comments 
I was unfortunately not aware of this information. good to know. 
To be honest, today I'm using version 9 update 2 and I'm still using the fast query. Now I know have what I need to do :)