# Sitecore 10.1 Fast Query CompositeDataProvider System.NullReferenceException

Tags: sitecore-query

I have faced an issue with `fast queries` in **Sitecore 10.1**.

When I execute `SelectSingleItem` *fast* query:

```
 Database.GetDatabase("master").SelectSingleItem($"fast:/sitecore/system/Modules//*[@@templateid='{Constants.Templates.DemoModule}']");
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception: System.NullReferenceException
Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Sitecore.Kernel
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.CompositeDataProvider.TransformQuery(String query, Boolean& allowMerging, String& filterPathId)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.CompositeDataProvider.SelectIDsInternalFast(String query, Boolean singleItemQuery, CallContext context)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.CompositeDataProvider.SelectSingleID(String query, CallContext context)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataProviders.DataProvider.SelectSingleID(String query, CallContext context, DataProviderCollection providers)
   at Sitecore.Data.DataManager.SelectSingleItem(String query, Boolean& processed)
   at Sitecore.Data.DefaultDatabase.SelectSingleItem(String query)
```

It works fine if I remove **"fast:"** prefix in query. Fast queries also work fine in previous `Sitecore` versions **(tested in all 9.0-10.0)**.

The problem is that it is a bad idea to change all `queries` in project. Is there any solution without project refactoring?

Comment: That's a really good idea to remove all the "fast:" queries

Comment: @MarekMusielak, any arguments/proofs?

Comment: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/16203/what-are-the-limitations-of-fast-query

Comment: I believe fast query was deprecated in 10.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fast:// Query is not supported in Sitecore 10.1 and onwards.

Sources: http://www.stockpick.nl/english/the-end-of-sitecore-fast-query/

Official Source:
https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform/101/Sitecore%20Experience%20Platform%20101/Release%20Notes#Highlights

Sitecore Experience Platform 10.1.0 includes:

- ​You can now use the content hierarchy to assign a behavior profile to multiple items.
  ​​- You can now use content tags to assign a behavior profile to multiple items.​
- The Collection database now supports scalable reads.
- You can now use the new ​Data Purge CLI tool to remove unwanted contact data from the Experience Database​.
- **Sitecore Fast Query has been deprecated.**

[...] and more

Comment: Thank you! I didn`t know that.