# How to get the descendants of the values/folder in `Read-Variable` command using `Fast` query?

Tags: powershell-extensions

I have here a `Read-Variable` command that will make you select any content folder.

```
$root= Get-Item master:\content\home

$selectFolder= Read-Variable -Parameters
    @{ Name = "root"; Title="Start Item"; Root="/sitecore/content/"}
    -Description "This Dialog shows less editors, it doesn’t need tabs as there is less of the edited variables"
    -Title "Initialise various variable types (without tabs)" -Width 500 -Height 480 -OkButtonName "Proceed" -CancelButtonName "Abort"
```

Now, I want to get the descendants of the folder selected above that are based on this template id `{FF24F59C-E4B4-4130-A119-036A02B3543B}` using fast query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the script below.

1. First initial value for `$selectFolder` is set.
2. Then `Read-Variable` is called and `Name = "selectFolder"` path says that whatever is selected in the popup should be set back to `$selectFolder` variable.
3. Then the query is executed to search in `master` database with full item path and template of your choice.

```bsh
$selectFolder = Get-Item master:\content\home

$result = Read-Variable -Parameters `
    @{ Name = "selectFolder"; Title="Start Item"; Root="/sitecore/content/"} `
    -Description "This Dialog shows less editors, it doesn’t need tabs as there is less of the edited variables" `
    -Title "Initialise various variable types (without tabs)" -Width 500 -Height 480 -OkButtonName "Proceed" -CancelButtonName "Abort"

$queryResult = Get-Item Master: -Query ($selectFolder.Paths.FullPath + "//*[@@templateid='{76036F5E-CBCE-46D1-AF0A-4143F9B557AA}']")
$queryResult
```

Comment: Is it possible to use fast query for that?
`$query = "fast: $selectFolder.Paths.FullPath//*[@@TemplateID='{FF24F59C-E4B4-4130-A119-036A02B3543B}']"`

Comment: Don't use fast query: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/12064/why-we-should-not-use-fast-queries-in-sitecore